# What's the correct IOS regex

Tags: ios, regex

I basically am expecting a string in the form of \w+:\w+ or \w+:\w+:\w+. I made a regex that can match each of those cases individually ...

```
NSRegularExpression *individualConstraintRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(\\w+?):(\\w+?)$" options:0 error:NULL];
```

and

```
NSRegularExpression *individualConstraintRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(^\\w+?):(\\w+?):(\\w+?)$" options:0 error:NULL];
```

However I tried to use the '|' symbol to achieve an OR effect but it doesnt work.

```
NSRegularExpression *individualConstraintRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(\\w+?):(\\w+?):(\\w+?)$|^(\\w+?):(\\w+?)$" options:0 error:NULL];
```

I'm sure the solution is simple, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression puts an OR in between of wrong subexpressions, i.e. `$|^` is an "OR" between `^` and `$`, making any match impossible.

Use parentheses for proper grouping:

```
NSRegularExpression *individualConstraintRegex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(?:(\\w+?):(\\w+?):(\\w+?))|(?:(\\w+?):(\\w+?))$"
                         options:0
                           error:NULL
];
```

`(?:...)` are non-capturing parentheses. They group parts of your expression without creating a new *capturing group*. I also moved the common anchors `^` and `$` outside the brackets.

Note that since `:` is *not* a word character, you can drop the reluctant qualifier `?`, and use `+` instead. Another alternative would be making the third `:\\w+` part optional, like this:

```
NSRegularExpression *individualConstraintRegex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(\\w+)[:](\\w+)(?:[:](\\w+))?$"
                         options:0
                           error:NULL
];
```

I added `[:]` around columns for readability. They are not necessary.

Comment: @Nate I misplaced the `?` in the second expression. Could you try it now?